# If $\chi\in\operatorname{Irr}(G)$, is $\chi$ always afforded by $kGe_\chi$, and why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

If $G$ is a finite group, and $\chi$ is an irreducible character, does the left $kG$-module $kGe_\chi$ always afford $\chi$ ($k$ a field), and serve as a representative of the $\chi$-isotypic component?

I'm wondering because many texts, like Isaac's, will just pick some representatives $M_i$ of the irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$ modules, but not write them more explicitly as $\mathbb{C}Ge_\chi$, if that is the case.

I was hoping to check the trace of $h\in G$ acting on an element $\sum_{g\in G}c_gge_\chi$, but I'm stumped as how to do so. My question is inspired by the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241080/if-chi-a-character-of-a-torus-t-in-algebraic-group-g-and-e-affords-c), saying one can take the module affording a $\chi$ character on a torus $T$ to just be $kTe_\chi$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}G e_{\chi}$ contains $\dim V_{\chi}$ copies of the irreducible representation $V_{\chi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an irreducible character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$, the $\mathbb CG$-module $\mathbb CGe_\chi$ affords the character $\chi(1)\chi$. See [James-Liebeck 2001, [Proposition 14.26](https://books.google.com/books?id=PiJMr6kZP44C&pg=PA146)]. In other words, $\mathbb CGe_\chi$ does not affords the character $\chi$ unless it is linear. (cf. Every irreducible character of a finite abelian group is linear.)

Comment: Thanks. So really $\mathbb{C}Ge_\chi\simeq\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\chi(1)}V_\chi$, where $V_\chi$ is the irreducible representation affording $\chi$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.